Selenium/Python cannot find element name
I am new to automation. I was creating a task using Python/Selenium to open a link, click a few buttons to navigate to a search icon, input the value I want in that search box. Now here is the problem, when we search something, it filters the results in real time in a table. Up to the point where I insert the search value, everything works fine. However, I want it to double click a row which then opens a modal.
The problem is, I am unable to right click on that row, to give Selenium the element that it needs to click. When I inspect element the whole page to look for that element (table row), I can't see anything that is related to that table that it displays.
I am very sorry if this is confusing, I don't really know how to explain it..
Basically, I want to find the hidden element name, that is not visible on inspect element, and I can't even right click when I hover over that table.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Sounds like an embedded component/file.  (OR they just have an event handler for right-click) Check the inspector (F12, Elements section) carefully opening up each section to see where it might be.  You can select/hover over the DOM elements in inspector and they will highlight in the view.
